# Get Text of parent Node Except child Node text using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<para>Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements
<ul class="listbullet2">
<li class="listbullet2">Server counts up to 25,000</li>
<li class="listbullet2">Millions of drives</li>
<li class="listbullet2">Millions of encryption keys</li>
</ul>
</para>
```

Current Output : -

```
<para>Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements Server counts up to 25,000Millions of drivesMillions of encryption keys</para>
```

Required Output :-

```
 <para>Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements <li>Server counts up to 25,000</li> <li>Millions of drives</li> <li>Millions of encryption keys</li> </para>
```

We need to get text "Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements" currently it is giving me complete content. Can anyone tell code for this?

Comment: Post the codes that 'is giving you complete content'

Comment: <para>Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements
            Server counts up to 25,000Millions of drivesMillions of encryption keys</para>


Required as 
              <para>Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements
            <li>Server counts up to 25,000</li>
<li>Millions of drives</li>
<li>Millions of encryption keys</li>
</para>

Comment: [edit] your question to provides more detailed info. Never put essential information in comment please. Also, what was asked is your C# codes, we've seen some XML so far (maybe enough) but still no C# codes to base the answer on

Answer (score 0):

Although your sample seems like an html, here is a solution with Linq2Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
xDoc.Root.Elements().Remove();
var txt = xDoc.Root.Value; //=>Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements
```

Answer (score 0):

Another working Linq to XML solution:

```
XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xml);
var res = elem.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault().Value;

Console.WriteLine(res); // Scales to meet individual data privacy requirements
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            foreach (XElement para in doc.Descendants("para"))
            {
                para.ReplaceNodes(para.Descendants("li"));
            }​
```

Comment: This is an XML Linq solution since it is using XElement (not element).  This is better than all other solutions because it will work on multiple "para" tags, not just the first.  It also keeps everything intact in the document except for the one change.  Don't blame me that linq needs a type which prevented me from using a traditional linq solution.